# What is the correct syntax for this Elixir expression?

Tags: elixir, anonymous-function

I have been proferred this code snippet, which the author has not tested,

```elixir
|> (fn l ->[?[, Enum.map(l, &([inspect(limit: :infinity), ?\n])), ?]] end).()
```

as part of a sequence of pipelined commands which converts data from a CSV file to  a `struct` using the [DataMorph](https://github.com/robmckinnon/data_morph) library, and outputs the result as a regular Elixir list for input into Elixir source - ie adding the surrounding brackets, and separating the elements of the list with commas.

This is what the sequence is meant to look like:

```
File.stream!('tmp.csv') \
|> DataMorph.structs_from_csv("open-register", :iso_country) \
|> (fn l ->[?[, Enum.map(l, &([inspect(limit: :infinity), ?\n])), ?]] end).()
|> (&File.write('output.txt',&1)).()
```

This is the error message when it is run in `iex`:

```
* (CompileError) iex:55: invalid args for &, expected an expression in the format of &Mod.fun/arity, &local/arity or a capture containing at least one argument as &1, got: [inspect(limit: :infinity), 10]
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.|>/2
             iex:55: (file)
```

Where is the fault in the snippet?

Comment: Does this work? `|> (fn l ->[?[, Enum.map(l, &([inspect(&1, limit: :infinity), ?\n])), ?]] end).()`

Comment: @Dogbert It compiles correct and adds the opening and closing brackets but it is not including the separating commas. That is the tricky part because a test must be made to ensure it is not the last item before it is appended.

Comment: There is no code in that which will separate the items with a comma. How about `|> (fn l ->[?[, Enum.map(l, &([inspect(&1, limit: :infinity), ?\n])) |> Enum.intersperse(?,), ?]] end).()`? Can you post the data and the expected output?

Comment: Your suggestion partly worked, but the comma is prepended to the subsequent entries, instead of being appended and causes a syntax error. ie `,%StructType.TplParams{xxx`  instead of the comma being appended to the previous line and the next one starting `%StructType.TplParams{xxx`.


https://pastebin.com/DCrpNDUh


I think the correct way is use the `,` in the `inspect` formula, then use the `\n` in the `intersperse` function. I will give that a try.

Comment: After trying it with `|> (fn l ->[?[, Enum.map(l, &([inspect(&1, limit: :infinity), ?,])) |> Enum.intersperse(?\n), ?]] end).() \``  there is an extra `,` on the last one, but `iex` accepted the output in an assignment. Perhaps it treats the blank item after the `,` as an nil element or ignores it in the parsing.

Comment: I've posted an answer which intersperses with `",\n"`. I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error can be fixed by adding `&1` as the first argument to the partial application syntax:

```
|> (fn l ->[?[, Enum.map(l, &([inspect(&1, limit: :infinity), ?\n])), ?]] end).()
```

This code doesn't include a separating comma. For that, if you want to stay with producing an iolist, I'd recommend using `Enum.intersperse`:

```
iex(1)> [1, 2, [3], [4, 5]] |> (fn l ->[?[, Enum.map(l, &inspect(&1, limit: :infinity)) |> Enum.intersperse(",\n"), ?]] end).() |> IO.puts
[1,
2,
[3],
[4, 5]]
```

I'd also break this into multiple lines for readability:

```
[1, 2, [3], [4, 5]]
|> (fn list ->
  elements = Enum.map(list, &inspect(&1, limit: :infinity)) |> Enum.intersperse(",\n")
  [?[, elements, ?]]
end).()
|> IO.puts
```

Comment: Could you explain/read out the second parameter of the original Enum.map : `&(&1, [inspect(limit: :infinity), ?\n])`.


It seems to me a function which takes its first parameter, inspects it and conatenates a new line to to it.


Does the square bracket around it mean 'make a list of the sequence'? And what does the outer '&' do?


It seems to be a function as well.

Comment: Oops, my answer had a typo. I've fixed it now. `&([inspect(&1, limit: :infinity), ?\n])` is a shorter syntax of and therefore equivalent to this: `fn x -> [inspect(x, limit: :infinity), ?\n] end`. Let me know if that doesn't make everything clear.

Comment: Does the surrounding square bracket mean the result of the function is turned into a list? It seems that the type of the evaluation would be different if the `inspect` and the newline were not in tthe brackets. I am more used to the explicitness of procedural languages

Comment: Yes, the `&` starts the anonymous function. The outermost parentheses are also optional, e.g. `&[&1, &1]` is the same as `fn x -> [x, x] end`.

Comment: How about the `&` in the `(&File.write('output.txt',&1)).()`? It doesn't seem to make the expression an anonymous function.

Comment: `&File.write('output.txt',&1)` == `fn x -> File.write('output.txt', x) end`. See also: http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#partials-and-function-captures-in-elixir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142412/discussion-between-vfclists-and-dogbert).