# Is there a tool in Elixir that can display a break down of how an expression is evaluated?

Tags: elixir

I have this one-liner from this question - [What is the correct syntax for this Elixir expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568312/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-this-elixir-expression).

```
|> (fn l ->[?[, Enum.map(l, &([inspect(&1, limit: :infinity), ?\n])) \
|> Enum.intersperse(?,), ?]] end).()
```

Is there a tool in Elixir that can display a breakdown of how it is evaluated?

Comment: I think you'd be better off refactoring this into multiple lines like I did in http://stackoverflow.com/a/43569911/320615. This really is quite hard to read with the long piped expression in the middle of a list.

Comment: I am new to these list processing functions and would avoid this kind of code in every day use. It is more to understand how these Elixir phrases are constructed in order to prepare me to read Haskell  in the future  ;).

In any case I should have put the second pipelined command on a separate line and I have done so now. My need for a tool which shows me how these expressions are parted and executed still remains.

Comment: Compared with other languages it is the absence of the use of brackets to delineate the various elements of expressions that cause difficulty for me.

Comment: One way to see some code with explicit parentheses is to parse and stringify it: `"a B.c |> D.e + f g h + i" |> Code.string_to_quoted! |> Macro.to_string #=> "a(B.c() |> D.e() + f(g(h + i)))"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the main problem you face seems to be in recognizing what the arguments to a parentheses-less function call are in complex expressions, you can parse a string to Elixir AST (`Code.string_to_quoted!/1`) and back (`Macro.to_string/1`), which will add explicit parentheses wherever there's a function call.

```
iex(1)> "a B.c |> D.e + f g h + i" |> Code.string_to_quoted! |> Macro.to_string
"a(B.c() |> D.e() + f(g(h + i)))"
```